# How does the Process Scheduler in iPhone OS really work internally?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, scheduler, multitasking

I want to know this more in detail. Is it a realtime scheduler? An interactive scheduler? How exactly does the process scheduler in iPhone OS work? Did Apple publish some technical notes or document that describes these things in deep detail?

I want to know every detail about it. What strategy is it following? First-Come First-Served? Shortest Job First? Shortest-Remaining-Time, Shortest-Remaining-Processing-Time? Round Robin? Priority Scheduling or even Multilevel Feedback Queue Scheduling? Shortest-Elapsed-Time? Deadline-dependent Scheduling?

Some of the Apple guys who wrote all this are on SO for sure. Please answer.

Comment: Given the last eight or so questions you've asked (all related to iPhone concurrency, all in the last day), I kind of get the impression that you're kind of dancing around some larger issue that is your *real* question.

Comment: right, I do have a real question. But I want to answer that myself by doing some deep research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the iPhone OS kernel is similar to the Mach kernel on the Mac, the ["Mach Scheduling and Thread Interfaces"](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/scheduler/scheduler.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000905-CH211-BEHJDFCA) section of the [Kernel Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/About/About.html) states

> Like Mach and most BSD UNIX systems,
>   it contains an advanced scheduler
>   based on the CMU Mach 3 scheduler.

The remainder of that section describes the scheduler in detail.